# How can I undo a poor edit of my question?

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

For some reason [my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59047/why-is-does-unzip-on-linux-give-an-compressed-winnt-security-missing-error) was edited poorly by a moderator on the Unix SE with bad grammar, and now it's getting downvoted. I don't understand why after I denied the edit, the edit went through.

The original post simply asked about why an international zipped file couldn't be unzipped using unzip in the terminal. Now the question has been edited poorly.

Comment: You can visit the [post revisions page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/59047/revisions) and roll back to a previous version.

Comment: It was still updated after I denied the revision.

Comment: A moderator does not need approval for the edit. You can roll back as Martijn said. Though in this particular case a simple correction might suffice as well. Not all is bad.

Comment: @graphicsman: It was not a suggested edit; there was nothing to deny there.

Comment: I don't see any poor grammar, in fact I think he improved the question.  The only problem I see is that they cut the tags down, there should probably be some more relevant tags on it.

Comment: well the edit was done very poorly and unnecessary.  Giles edited it a month ago and the new edit served no purpose other than confusion.

Comment: @LanceRoberts There was a "Why is does..." in the title. But the "is" could have simply been removed. Other than that the edit seemed fine to me.

Comment: So you cant deny a poorly edited thread if the moderator forces it from what you are saying?

Comment: @Bart, thanks, missed that.

Comment: @graphicsman Nope. Nor can you from those who have editing privileges (A 2k privilege). You can only roll it back or make corrections.

Comment: @graphicsman, all he seems to have done is edited the title, adjusted some formatting and added some more text in the form of a question. The only 'poor grammar' appears to be the "why is does' which is most likely him forgetting to remove an 'is' or a 'does'

Comment: Ok, but at the time I didn't understand why the edit was done when it wasn't needed and confused people when they saw the new edit.

Comment: You can be absolutely certain that the post isn't getting downvoted because of that extra "is" or "does". Moreover, it already has 5 upvotes. One/two downvotes doesn't make any difference. So chill and relax :-)

Comment: I see you don't like edits that improve your posts.

Comment: Without the question in question, there's no way to give a good answer; since all good answers have context.

Comment: I'd prefer it just be deleted but I suppose that won't happen.

Comment: Unlikely. Live with it.

Comment: OK, why do you feel that your question was “edited poorly”?   mattdm♦ (1) significantly improved your question’s title, (2) cut out the “I've … thought about asking it …” fluff, (3) turned it into a real question (look at your original post –– there is no explicit question there … and the one you added in revision 6 was awkwardly worded), and (4) made one grammatical error that was so trivial that ***I*** didn’t see it until I read Bart’s comment –– and I can usually spot _every_ editorial error.  There’s no way you got downvotes because of that tiny grammatical error.  What’s your complaint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hit the date link where it says edited, then find the version you like and hit the rollback button, and it will revert to that version.

Note, that I'm not saying you should do that in your case since most of the editing was good.  Just go edit what you want into it.

Comment: the edit wasn't good and didn't need an edit though.  The edit was done then people were lost about what I was asking.  I've already reverted it back to what Giles had.

Comment: @graphicsman Then we will have to agree to disagree. The title became more descriptive as a result of the edit, and an actual question was edited in. Admittedly the misspelling of "collegue" was missed. But I'm sure you'll correct that now. ;)

Comment: @Bart thanks for explaining to me why when I denied the edit it went through anyway.

Comment: @graphicsman You will not have denied that edit. The edit will not have come up for review. There is also no rejected suggested edit in your history. So I don't know what you rejected...

Comment: @Bart thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with Lance, I think the edit was ok. The first part of your question is just waffle:

> "So this is something for debate I've asked a few people and just thought about asking it here."

Honestly, people don't care to have to read through all of that before getting to the real meat and two veg of the question. I usually edit that kind of thing out, it doesn't tell us anything of value. We assume you've probably done some research before hitting the site, you don't need to tell us about "asking a few people".

The question title edit was fine too: "Issue with internationally zipped files" doesn't really give much away, the word "Issue" is a way of getting around saying "Problem" which is banned from use in question titles.

The title edit was far a far more descriptive summary of the issue you're trying to solve. Vague titles such as "Issue with [insert thing]" will less likely attract folks who hover over the new questions list.

If you think about it, people searching for solutions to the same problem are going to be searching using the error message generated by the tool used. They aren't going to search for "Issue with internationally zipped files".

Trust your site mods, they know what they're doing.

Comment: Yes. This. [Trust your site mods, they know what they're doing.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/551/in-praise-of-moderators)

Comment: (But in all seriousness, I did upvote this answer.)